# What are the chances of getting Javascript long running script error when manipulating string

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer

I am designing a SQL engine. From the UI the user will select certain parameters and based on those parameter I will design a SQL statement. User will have option to join tables, apply conditions, create temp tables, ability to apply many SQL in-build functions etc. I will write many functions which will look at the input and based that perform some action which will ultimately give a SQL statement.

1. I can do this code using any server side language but we want to try JavaScript.
2. Obviously this will require lot of string manipulation.

I am just worried if this will result "“**A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your compute may become unresponsive.**" on IE or "**A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue**" on Firefox.

I know I am not sharing any code & the question is little subjective. But I am sure some of you may have faced similar issues/challenge in your previous assignment & your valuable suggestions will be a big help.

Comment: *"I can do this code using any server side language but we want to try JavaScript."* JavaScript can be used server-side if you like. It is and *always has been* an utter and complete myth that it's a "client-side language."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thank you for quick reply. I know I can use node JS but when I said JavaScript, I meant executing the code on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, you are asking if there is a risk of getting that dreaded message when doing a couple of string manipulations.

If you want to only construct the query in the browser, then I think you are fine, as you won't have to, say, concatenate 1000 strings, or search a string amongst 1000. The only risk I would say is if you intend to do complicated regexp operations on big strings.
If I misunderstood, a few example of the string manipulations you intend to do would help.

Of course, I am assuming you will send and run the SQL queries in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: I am looking at constructing the query using lots of if and else block across multiple functions. I will execute the SQL query in asynchronous manner. I do not think I will use complicated regexp on string. But every query will go through lot of if else condition even when the actual query does not need it.

Comment: Then you won't have any problem. On any modern computer or even mobile device, you can execute A LOT of if instructions before the browser starts complaining.